# Installing new Text-To-Speech languages on Windows 7 32bit Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, language, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices

I've been hoping to install a Spanish Text-To-Speech voice for use with a vb.Net program I'm creating.

I've downloaded `MSSpeech_TTS_es-ES_Helena`from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27224 and installed it.I also have installed the `Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime` that's required with it.

However when I go to Speech Properties in Control Panel, I still only have option to use Microsoft Anna. I cannot see Helena anywhere.

I should mention I have Windows 7 32bit Home Premium Service Pack 1. This means I can't change system language as I don't have Ultimate. I wouldn't have thought it would effect system voices though.

This is fast becoming annoying. I've checked all over the internet and even risked changing registry keys to no avail.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

'' How to add more TTS Voices in Windows 7/8.1/10 ''

Link Youtube - https://youtu.be/ojwNJmqoPDk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1118632)